# How to Make Animation shape in MS Excel

Tags: excel

Open Office has an option to animate text in a shape; is there a similar feature in Excel?

Comment: Please refer to this page, hope it'll help..
https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Impress_Guide/Using_slide_animation_effects

Comment: Hi Elusive, Thanks for your Prompt response. I know the option were available in open office , But my question is does the same facility available in Excel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer, below is the macro which can make it succeed.

```
Sub Tester1()

Dim sp As String
Dim sTxt As String
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
Dim Start, delay

sTxt = "Hi there!!"

    For y = 0 To 25                                               '15 Loops through the scrolling
    For x = 1 To 60                                           'Index number of times
    Start = Timer                                         'Set start to internal timer
    delay = Start + 0.15                                  'Set delay for .15 secs
    Do While Timer < delay                                'Do the display routine

        [D6] = Space(x) & sTxt                            'Show 1 str @ a time
        DoEvents                                          'do there things
    Loop                                                  'Loop until delay is up
    DoEvents
    Start = Timer                                         'and reset the timer
    delay = Start + 0.15                                  'and the delay
Next x                                                    'Show the next str
Next y                                                        'Do this again - 15

[D6] = ""                                                     'Reset

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of excel are you trying to animate a shape? What would you use it for? I haven't seen any shape animations on excel. It might be possible to do it via VBA.

Comment: excel version is 2010. could please share the VBA Code for animation in shape text?